# Cannot add a property in an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, api, object, array.prototype.map

I have an array that contains objects and I want to add to each object a property called type with value "ecosystem".
Take this array as an example:

```
[
    {
        "public": true,
        "_id": "8484848484",
        "name": "CityName",
        "country": {
            "public": true,
            "_id": "2151515151",
            "name": "CountryName",
            "createdAt": "some time",
            "updatedAt": "some time",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "landscapeImageUrl": "some url"
    }
]
```

I wrote this function where first I filter by the searchLine, and then I add the ecosystem type:

```
const searchEcosystems = (ecosystems, searchLine = '') => {
  const filteredEcosystems = ecosystems.filter(
    (ecosystem) =>
      ecosystem.name && ecosystem.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchLine)
  );
  const ecosystemsResult = filteredEcosystems.map(ecosystem => {
    ecosystem.type = 'ecosystem'
    return ecosystem
  })
  console.log('ecosystemsResult: ', ecosystemsResult);

  return ecosystemsResult;
};
```

The problem is that the result never has the type property. Somehow it is not being added. I guess it is a noob mistake but I cannot figure out what is the problem.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: the same object provided on the top with another property (under landscapeImageUrl) called type: with value 'ecosystem'

Comment: I ran it and it worked for me just fine.

Comment: The the code is correct, right? I ran this also on chrome console and it works but not working on express. CAnnot figure out why

Comment: Maybe you need to sho more info on this like how do you call it, how is the JSON fetched etc.